# Popover controllers vs. the menu popover for SplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I use a floating popover to present suggestions in my UI. When the user wants to select an item from the menu bar in the splitview controller, the first tap just dismisses the popover. Therefore, the user has to tap twice, to activate a menu item.

[image: Here it is in action]

If the user wants to activate the trash can, he has to tap it twice. Once to dismiss the other popover, and once to activate the trash can.

What's the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess here - but perhaps `passThroughViews` - add the button view and then in the button action, dismiss the popover (need to determine if it is active). A bit hacky but could work.

Comment: Close! The solution is to add the toolbar to the passThroughViews, not just the buttons. Thank you for your help!